# LinearLayout children - all views should have the same height and at least wrap their content

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Here's my (simplified) code example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llCustomValueContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- some content of undefined height -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- following content is of undefined height as well -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValueTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**What I want**

- `llCustomValueContainer` should derive it's hight from it's highest child (`llTitle` and `tvValueTop`)
- `llTitle` and `tvValueTop` should have the SAME height (because I want the selector and touches to use the full height) and should at least wrap their content

**Problem**

Everything works, as long as the height of `llTitle` is higher than the height of `tvValueTop`. Can I somehow change the layout so that I `llTitle` and `tvValueTop` have the same height and at least wrap their content (the smaller view should be stretched to have the same height as the bigger one)? I don't want them to look like being of the same height (by centering the smaller one vertically for example) but I really want them to be of the same height because both views can be clicked.

Comment: why you don't use android:layout_weight="1" in TextView

Comment: I dont understand your question. You say two child should have same height but you also say that your parent layout should derive its height from its highest child layout's height. Can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a height of `wrap_content` for the outer `LinearLayout`, and use a height of `match_parent` for both of the children.

I know it seems a little bit odd, but as long as **none** of the children of the outer `LinearLayout` have a deterministic size (either fixed or `wrap_content`), the resulting behavior will be that each child is the height of the tallest child.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, that's something I completely forgot... This works